# Explode a string on upper case characters?

Tags: php, string

Ho can i explode `$param` string into `$chunks` pieces based on upper-case characters?

```
$string = 'setIfUnmodifiedSince';
$method = substr($string, 0, 3);
$param  = substr($string, 3);

// Split $param and implode with '-' separator
$chunks = splitAtUpperCase($param); // Chunks are: 'If', 'Unmodified' and 'Since'
$field  = implode('-', $chunks); // Get If-Unmodified-Since HTTP field name
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) on `[A-Z]` should do:

```
function splitAtUpperCase($s) {
        return preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

---

**EDIT**
If you don't *need* the array itself, you can just preprend uppercase characters (except the first) with a hyphen (`-`):

```
preg_replace('/(?<!^)([A-Z])/', '-\\1', $param);
```

([demo](http://www.ideone.com/nWEKv))

Comment: Hmm, JRL provided the [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) before I got mine [working](http://www.ideone.com/4ux5G) :) Also, notice `$chucks` vs. `$chunks`

Comment: Time to learn regular expression i suppose. Thanks for this elegant solution!

Comment: `PREG_SPLIT_NOT_EMPTY`, yes excellent! Thank you for including that!

Answer (score 6):

```
$chunks = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $string);
```

Comment: Also need to `array_shift` the result.

Comment: array_shift is only needed if the sentence begins with an upper-case... if it starts with a lower case, don't array_shift()

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
function splitAtUpperCase($string){
    return preg_replace('/([a-z0-9])?([A-Z])/','$1-$2',$string);
}

$string = 'setIfUnmodifiedSince';
echo splitAtUpperCase($string);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to convert string with lover case you can @jensgram's  code, where I have changed hyphen `(-)` to underscore `(_)`

```
strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<!^)([A-Z])/', '_\\1', $param));
```

as I was looking for.

Comment: Changing one character in another person's answer does not make this answer valuable.