# How to case-sensitively split a string using PHP's explode() function?

Tags: php, regex

An Example:

```
$return = explode("case-sensitivy","nameCaseExample");

print_r($return);
```

Return:

```
array(
  [0] => "name",
  [1] => "Case",
  [2] => "Example",
);
```

Comment: Could you please translate that into english?

Comment: You wouldn't use explode() for this, but something like [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: That code certainly doesn't return what you say.

Comment: So, you want to split the string on the "camel-case" letters?

Comment: Sorry, just now I noticed.

The question is "How can you separate a case-sensitivy string with 'explodes' PHP function"?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577300/explode-a-string-on-upper-case-characters). You can't do it with explode, but use the code provided there.

Comment: What about when you get this: `testINGSomethingHere`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preg_split to do this:

```
$str = 'nameCaseExample';
$arr = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$str);
print_r($arr);
```

Which will return:

```
Array ( [0] => name [1] => Case [2] => Example )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions. Try this:

`preg_match_all('/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/', "nameCaseExample", $results);`

The array containing all the words will be saved in $results[0].

Comment: OK. But I need the first character is lowcase.

Comment: @robertaodj check this https://eval.in/86264

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. Creo que esto es lo que quieres.

```
$return = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',"nameCaseExample");

print_r($return);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => Case
    [2] => Example
)
```