# php explode the values and make spaces

Tags: php, explode

I have the string like this in database. Sorry to say but I can change the database.

```
TuesLunch|MonLunch|MonDinner|TuesBKfast
```

So generally it has all the days name with Dinner, Lunch and BKfast
Now I want to make this string to show in php like this

```
Tues Lunch 
Mon Lunch 
Mon Dinner
Tues BKfast
```

I have done so far

```
$weekdays = TuesLunch|MonLunch|MonDinner|TuesBKfast;
$days = explode('|',$weekdays);
```

So can someone tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577300/explode-a-string-on-upper-case-characters

Comment: You know that every time someone puts compound data like this in a database E.F. Codd's ghost rises from his grave and murders a kitten? I'd really look at getting access to change the database if I were you - you don't want kitten deaths on your conscience do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_split` which is basically `explode()` with regex: (Below regex splits on capital letter)

```
foreach($days as $day){
  $splitUppercase = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $day, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  $str = "";
  for($i = 0; $i < count($splitUppercase); $i++){
     if($i > 0){
        $str .= $splitUppercase[$i];
     } else {
        $str .= $splitUppercase[$i]." ";
     }
  }
  $str .= "\n";
  echo $str;
}
```

Comment: And in case of `TuesBKfast` ?

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Tues [1] => B [2] => Kfast ) `

Comment: @Alex Yes, so? `$str` contains exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: I just edited your answer, I will upvote you later need to wait vote lock.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do this:

```
$weekdays = "TuesLunch|MonLunch|MonDinner|TuesBKfast";
$days = explode('|', $weekdays);

$strings = [];
foreach ($days as $day) {
  preg_match_all('/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/', $day, $results);
  $strings[] = implode($results[0], ' ');
}
print_r($strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as you expected:

```
$weekdays = "TuesLunch|MonLunch|MonDinner|TuesBKfast";
$days = explode('|', $weekdays);

function spacify($str, $delim = ' ') {
    $str = preg_replace('/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/', "$1$delim$2", $str);
    return $str;
}

foreach (spacify($days) as $key => $val){
    echo $val."<br>";
}
```